# What's the cheapest character to get farming at 60?

Tags: diablo-iii

I played D3 as soon as it came out over a year ago. I hear a lot has changed in the game, and I'm looking to get back into it.

I leveled a Barb, Monk, Demon Hunter, and Wizard to level 60. What character would be the cheapest to start to gear up so that I could farm gold/gear for all my characters. Please no "whatever you most enjoy" answers, as I enjoyed all my characters, and from my understanding some are certainly cheaper to upgrade than others. From what I've read it sounds like Barbarians require extremely expensive gear, so for instance it seems reasonable to me that I should probably not start with my Barb. Is that correct? **What would you do if you were me and wanted to a single farming char that could farm high level fast and efficiently?**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good "investement/farming time granted" ratio I'd go in this order :

1. Barbarian : Really easy to gear up and start farming (even for monster power 10(mp 10))
2. Wizard : The permafrost built is really easy to achieve and you can find some reliable guide to help you on the official forum
3. Monk : The cookie cutter built for Monk is pretty cheap and will give you a good farming rate at mp 6-8 depending on how much you can put on the gear
4. DH/WD : To achieve a good farm rate with those character you will need a lot (and by a lot I mean A LOT) of gold, and even if you reach a near high end gear you wont be as fast as Barbarians or Wizards

However Barbarian has a really linear gameplay and might look boring to play, I personnaly play DH with ~400k dps unbuffed and can farm mp 10 with ease.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that high end gear is very expensive for barbarians, but that should not be a reason not to play a barbarian at all.

In fact you can get some basic gear to start farming with a barbarian very cheap. Gear that would have cost dozens of millions of gold a year ago.

The classes that still are the most effective at pure grinding are wizards and barbarians. It's also pretty easy to get them both geared at the beginning.